# Events are not getting added in calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the name for event and end date (without start date) in Google Sheets.

**Column B** is the name of the event and **column C** is end date.

The script says execution successful but events are not getting added in Google Calendar.

I am the owner and have full rights/permission.

Here's the script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar');
  var item = menu.addItem('Commit', 'syncCalendar');
  item.addToUi();
  }
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarid**");
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B250').getValue();
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C250').getValue()).getTime();
  var end =  new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C250').getValue()).getTime();
  eventCal.createEvent(name,new Date(start),new Date(end));
  Logger.log('Reminder is added to your calendar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a loop as follows

```
const cal = '################@gmail.com'

function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal);
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow()
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var start = spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var end = spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  name.forEach((n, i) => {
    try {
      var id = eventCal.createEvent(n, new Date(start[i].getTime()), new Date(end[i].getTime())).getId();
      console.log(id)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(i + ' ' + e)
    }
  })
  Logger.log('Reminder is added to your calendar');
}
```

[flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you. I get the following error: 

Error 
TypeError: start[i].getTime is not a function
(anonymous) @ code.gs:8
calendar @ code.gs:7

Comment: it works on my side; what the value in range C3:C250? have you blanks? are they dates or strings? did you get some event however? share a spreadsheet

Comment: Yes, there are some blanks. No events in calendar. Here is a photo: https://i.postimg.cc/FFpX84xV/image.png

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cfKpIrgRvt3EuOEs-Ti_rJL53QjE0u-f3stlZ4A8ro/copy - I have added the test or errors

Comment: in C you put `date (dd.mm.yyyy)` is that a comment or do you have really this? If so, we have to fetch the date and transform in real date!

Comment: Wow, thank you Mike! Please, advise me on the following error: 220 Exception: Service invoked too many times in a short time: calendar. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. 

How do I include delay between calls?

Comment: just after `try {` ... `try {Utilities.sleep(1000);`

Answer (score -1):

With the help of @Mike Steelson this script is working.

**However, when you run the code again, it creates duplicates in the calendar.**

Is there any way to avoid this?

```html
const cal = 'yourcalendarid@group.calendar.google.com'

function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal);
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow()
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var start = spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var end = spreadsheet.getRange('C3:C' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  name.forEach((n, i) => {
    try {
      var id = eventCal.createEvent(n, new Date(start[i].getTime()), new Date(end[i].getTime())).getId();
      console.log(id)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(i + ' ' + e)
    }
  })
  Logger.log('Reminder is added to your calendar');
}
```

Comment: Follow up questions should be posted as new questions, not as an answer.